# UML class diagrams connections if a class is used everywhere?

Tags: java, oop, uml, diagram, class-diagram

So in my project, some of the classes are: `Assembler`, `Controller`, `Part`, `StorageManager`, `StorageDepartment`.

A `Controller` consists of a list of `Part`s. `Assembler` creates a list of `Controller`s using a list of `Part`s. `StorageManager` gives the required parts to `Assembler`. `StorageManager` gets the `Part`s from `StorageDepartment` which gets the `Part`s from a `Supplier`.

My point is that almost every class in the Project uses the `Part` class. How am I supposed to connect all of the classes with the `Part` class in a class diagram? Connecting everything, does not seem logical, and would make the diagram cluttered. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all your classes have a dependency on `Part`, then that is what you should model in your diagram. If you think that is convoluted, change your design. You don't model your application based on how ugly it looks in a UML diagram.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes almost all classes have dependency on `Part` and I can't change the design. I was just thinking that a class diagram should be more readable than having a class connect to all the other ones. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just about presentation, you have a couple of options:

1) Use attribute notation instead of association edges. From the UML 2.4.1 Superstructure spec:

> Figure 7.24 shows that the attribute notation can be used for an association end owned by a class, because an association end owned by a class is also an attribute.

2) Just break it down into many small diagrams with just 3-4 classes each.

3) Compartmentalize your diagram. Many UML tools allow a class to appear in a diagram more than once. Even if you don't want many small diagrams (eg. because you want to have all the classes appear in a single diagram), you can break it down into smaller groups and thus avoid a big tangly mess of edges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The project allowed me to kind of divide it left and right with the `Part` right in the middle and it looks a lot better. Thanks again.